# High Scalability Question: How to sync data across multiple microservices

Tags: apache-kafka, message-queue, kafka-consumer-api, jms-topic, kafka-topic

I have the following use cases:

1. Assume you have two micro-services one AccountManagement and ActivityReporting that processes event U.
2. When a user registers, event U containing the user information will published into a broker for the two micro-services to process.
3. AccountManagement, and ActivityReporting microservice are replicated across two instances **each** for performance and scalability reasons.
4. Each microservice instance has a consumer listening on the broker topic. The choice of topic is so that both AccountManagement, and ActivityReporting can process U concurrently.

However, I want only one instance of AccountManagement to process event U, and one instance of ActivityReporting to process event U.

Please share your experience implementing a Consume Once per Application Group, broker system.

As this would effectively solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

If all your consumer listeners even from different instances have the same `group.id` property then only one of them will receive the message. You need to set this property when you initialise the consumer. So in your case you will need one `group.id` for AccountManagement and another for ActivityReporting.

Comment: Is this for kafka? Also, do you know if the producer also need to indicate if the message is consume once. As I imagine there would be case where you want all instances to get the message. Thanks

Comment: Yes, this is for Kafka. Producer does not affect the policy of the consuming of the messages. If you need all the instances consume the messages, each of them must have a different group.id

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend [Cadence Workflow](https://cadenceworkflow.io/) which is much more powerful solution for microservice orchestration.

It offers a lot of advantages over using queues for your use case.

- Built it exponential retries with unlimited expiration interval
- Failure handling. For example it allows to execute a task that notifies another service if both updates couldn't succeed during a configured interval.
- Support for long running heartbeating operations
- Ability to implement complex task dependencies. For example to implement chaining of calls or compensation logic in case of unrecoverble failures ([SAGA](https://microservices.io/patterns/data/saga.html))
- Gives complete visibility into current state of the update. For example when using queues all you know if there are some messages in a queue and you need additional DB to track the overall progress. With Cadence every event is recorded.
- Ability to cancel an update in flight.

See [the presentation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=llmsBGKOuWI) that goes over Cadence programming model.